# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'drafts' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'drafts' of null

Tags: javascript, react-native

I receive this **error** while retrieving data from storage. What is the reason?
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (`id: 3`):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'drafts' of null

```
 @action async masterProperty(obj) {
            let observations = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AuthStore.token); //active icon receiving keyed observations
            let objObservations = JSON.parse(observations); //json observations js translating to object
            let keyNames = Object.keys(obj);
            let inValid = false;
            for (let item of objObservations.drafts) {
              if (item.ui == this.getActiveUID) {
                inValid = true;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (inValid) {
              this.updateProp(obj);
            } else {
              this.newProperty(obj);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error: `Cannot read property "drafts" of null`.

The only place you use something.drafts is in the `for` loop:

`for (let item of objObservations.drafts)`.

This means that for some reason objObservations is null, and you get it from parsing the JSON you got from storage.
Now, when `Json.parse()` return null - it means it was passed a "null" JSON - which means the data retrieval from storage is goign wrong.

Try check the following:

1. check if a correct JSON object is returned from storage.
2. check that you actually have the information in storage- because a null return might indicate that you do not.
3. check that AsyncStorage actually uses promises and not maybe callbacks method for asynchrnousity - maybe that "await" fails because it does not use promises and than the value is not returned and `observations` stays empty.